# Is there a way to link a value from a website onto my console application on c#

Tags: c#, hyperlink

So this should be a fairly simple question. I'm experimenting with c#, and I was wondering if someone could help me do the following:

I'm trying to get the daily market value of gold through a website (www.moneymetals.com) and perform basic arithmetic functions with that value and print the results to the user.

What I want this basic application to do is 
1) grab the value from the website. Obviously this type of data is variable data as it fluctuates a lot
2) perform arithmetic such as multiplication on that value 
3) print the value to the user

Example: 
- Gold price today = $52 
- I have 5 grams of gold so $52 x 5 = 260
- Print the result

If someone could list out a skeleton of the code I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you !

Comment: That is not what Stack Overflow is for. If you don't want this post to be removed, you will need to post the code you have already worked on and any specific problems.

Comment: This can be done but please share what you have done and where you are stuck

Answer (score 2):

While you *could* fetch the HTML and parse it, that's typically quite a brittle approach.

In general it's much better if you can use an API provided by the web site owner to give the same information in a machine-readable format. It doesn't look like moneymetals.com has this - but https://metals-api.com/ exists for precisely that reason as far as I can see.

Their [pricing](https://metals-api.com/pricing) only allows 50 API calls per month on the free tier, which isn't many, but it might be okay if you're just looking to experiment.

You'd just need to make a web request (e.g. with `HttpClient`) and parse the JSON (e.g. with Json.NET) which should be simple.

There are no doubt plenty of other similar APIs you could use - you may want to hunt around for them. But I'd definitely try to use an API rather than parsing HTML if you possibly can.